# MySQL cannot connect via "localhost", only 127.0.0.1

Tags: php, mysql, localhost

this is somewhat of a mystery to me. The only way I can connect to MySQL is if I call it via "127.0.0.1" ... for example, my PHP connect script will NOT work with localhost

I'm running Mac OS X Lion, built-in apache2, MySQL, PHP, phpMyAdmin

mysqladmin:

```
count                             0
debug-check                       FALSE
debug-info                        TRUE
force                             FALSE
compress                          FALSE
character-sets-dir                (No default value)
default-character-set             auto
host                              (No default value)
no-beep                           FALSE
port                              0
relative                          FALSE
socket                            (No default value)
sleep                             0
ssl                               FALSE
ssl-ca                            (No default value)
ssl-capath                        (No default value)
ssl-cert                          (No default value)
ssl-cipher                        (No default value)
ssl-key                           (No default value)
ssl-verify-server-cert            FALSE
user                              (No default value)
verbose                           FALSE
vertical                          FALSE
connect-timeout                   43200
shutdown-timeout                  3600
plugin-dir                        (No default value)
default-auth                      (No default value)
```

Comment: This is probably more for Server fault, but make sure your hosts file has the localhost alias.

Comment: 127.0.0.1 localhost is in my hosts file.

Comment: Open command prompt and type `ping localhost` and see what it says.

Comment: 64 bytes from 127.0.0.1: icmp_seq=0 ttl=64 time=0.100 ms
64 bytes from 127.0.0.1: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.102 ms
64 bytes from 127.0.0.1: icmp_seq=2 ttl=64 time=0.096 ms

Answer (score 29, accepted):

MySQL will try to connect to the unix socket if you tell it to connect to "localhost". If you tell it to connect to 127.0.0.1 you are forcing it to connect to the network socket. So probably you have MySQL configured to only listen to the network socket and not to the file system socket.

What exactly is wrong with your unix socket is hard to tell. But I recommend you to read [this page](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/can-not-connect-to-server.html) on the MySQL reference guide. This should help you.

UPDATE:
Based on the updated question: The parameter "socket" should be something like this: "/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock". [This page in the Reference Manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/server-options.html#option_mysqld_socket) has some more information.

Here you have the beginning of my /etc/my.cnf file:

```
[mysqld]
datadir=/var/lib/mysql
socket=/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock
```

Your file should be similar. Then your problem should be solved. Don't forget to restart the MySQL server before you test it.

Comment: Wow: "A Unix socket file is used if you don't specify a host name or if you specify the special host name localhost." That seems...unintuitive. Hence all the other answers.

Comment: Thats good to know +1

Comment: I appreciate the theory... just don't know what the answer is.

Comment: @dcolumbus: As I already wrote it is hard to tell. What I can recommend you is to open a console and just write the command "mysql". Maybe you get more information then. Another thing is to look into the log file. Mine is located in the directory /var/log/ and is called mysql.log. Yours could have another name or another location. If you can provide us with more information then we can probably help you better.

Comment: Raffael, take a look at my post. I've pasted the mysqladmin information.

Comment: @dcolumbus: I have updated the answer. Now you should have everything you need in order to solve the problem.

Comment: php.ini has references to "/var/mysql/mysql.sock" (3 places to be exact) which need to be changed to "/tmp/mysql.sock" ... Thank you for your help!

Comment: Thanks @dcolumbus.  You solved a long-running mystery for me.

Answer (score 8):

You may have IPv6 enabled, its very possible localhost resolves to the ipv6 localhost, that is not defined in your msql config.

ive also had a problem where i had to add 'localhost' in place of '127.0.0.1' to the allowed subnets for that user, dont understand why (i was using ipv4 and it was a while ago) but its worth a try.

Comment: You can check this by seeing if 'host localhost' at the command line returns ::1 as well as 127.0.0.1. If so, you can either remove the ::1 mapping from /private/etc/hosts or reconfigure MySQL to listen on the IPv6 ::1 address as well as 127.0.0.1

Comment: I think I remember reading somewhere that IPv6 is enabled by default on Mac OS X ... is that the case?

Comment: ipv6 is enabled for pretty much all modern OS's these days, im on osx10.6 and its enabled by default.

Comment: wrong. Localhost has special meaning for mysql clients — check out https://serverfault.com/a/295300/67675

Answer (score 5):

For me, OSX's builtin php is configured to use a different unix-socket than homebrew's mysql. Thus it can't connect via localhost which utilizes that socket.

I fixed it with a quick hack by symlinking php's configured socket-path to point to the one mysql actually uses.

```
sudo ln -s /tmp/mysql.sock /var/mysql/mysql.sock
```

**The following diagnostic commands were very helpful.**

Check the default socket-paths used by php and mysql:

```
php -i | fgrep 'mysql.default_socket'
mysql -e 'show variables where variable_name = "socket"'
```

Connect using a specified socket:

```
php -r 'var_dump(mysql_connect("localhost:/tmp/mysql.sock", "user", "pass"));'
mysql --socket=/tmp/mysql.sock
```

Determine what kind of socket mysql client is using to connect:

```
lsof | egrep '^mysql .*(IPv|unix)'
```

Answer (score 2):

Could you check `mysql/conf/my.conf` (the directory structure should pretty much be the same on OSx) to see if `skip-networking` is uncommented? If so, add a `#` in-front of the line and restart the mysql-server.

I actually had a similar issue a while back (although that wasn't in OSx), so I thought it might be worth a shot.

Comment: Why did this get downvoted? An explanation would be helpful.

Comment: I didn't down-vote you, but your answer is actually the opposite of what the OP is asking. But I upvoted you because I struggled with the opposite condition — would connect via a socket, but NOT via network. By the way, I COULD NOT fix this via my.conf; I had to put it on the command line: "mysqlf --skip_networking=0 ..."

Answer (score 2):

I was able to recreate your same symptoms on my test box, hopefully this will help.

In MySQL, users are defined by two parts (name and host).  By default, MySQL will have 3 root users:

```
mysql> SELECT host,user,password FROM mysql.user WHERE user='root';
+-----------------------+------+-------------------------------------------+
| host                  | user | password                                  |
+-----------------------+------+-------------------------------------------+
| localhost             | root |                                           |
| localhost.localdomain | root |                                           |
| 127.0.0.1             | root | *PASSWORD_HASH_GOES_HERE                  |
+-----------------------+------+-------------------------------------------+
```

The password field will either be blank (no password) or have a hash stored.  If you set the password for one specific user, it doesn't automatically update all, since MySQL sees them as different users.

For example:

```
mysql> set password for 'root'@'127.0.0.1' = password('Password');
```

will update the password for `'root'@'127.0.0.1'`, but not `'root'@'localhost'` or `'root'@'localhost.localdomain'`

Take a look at the `skip_name_resolve` variable:

```
mysql> show variables like 'skip_name_resolve';
+-------------------+-------+
| Variable_name     | Value |
+-------------------+-------+
| skip_name_resolve | ON    |
+-------------------+-------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

By Default `skip_name_resolve` is `OFF`, and will attempt to resolve all IP Addresses to hostnames.  For example, if you connect as `'root'@'127.0.0.1'`, MySQL will change connect you as `'root'@'localhost'`.

If it is `ON`, MySQL will see and connect `'root'@'127.0.0.1'` and `'root'@'localhost'` as seperate users.  And they may or may not have different passwords, depending on how they were set.

---

So first, I would check to see any password differences:
`mysql> SELECT host,user,password FROM mysql.user WHERE user='root';`

If there are, you can fix them, or you can continue investigating.

Then I would check `skip_name_resolve`:
`mysql> show variables like 'skip_name_resolve';`

If it is `ON`, I would find out where it's being set (for example `/etc/my.cnf`) and remove it, unless there is a need for it.

Hopefully this helps you out!

Answer (score 2):

PHP is still trying to use the default socket location. This problem can appear if you have **moved the MariaDB/MySQL folder** from */var/lib/mysql* to another location. In order to solve the problem you have to define the new socket's location in the */etc/php.ini* file.

```
mysqli.default_socket =/newDBLocation/mysql/mysql.sock
```

Watch out, depending on which driver you use, you may have to specify the *pdo_mysql.default_socket=*!

In order to check your current directory run the following command in mysql:

```
select @@datadir;
```

Answer (score 2):

For people who are using CageFS with CloudLinux:

I recreated `/var/lib/mysql` because I was rebuilding MySQL server from scratch...

which unmounted the path from cagefs.
I know it's unrelated, but I was using cPanel and CloudLinux.
I couldn't verify why socket connection won't work, and finally, I realized.

adding `/var/lib/mysql` to `/etc/cagefs/cagefs.mp`
(if already there proceed to next step)
and running

```
cagefsctl --remount-all
```

fixed the problem

Comment: OMG! This is what fixed it for me! It was already in `/etc/cagefs/cagefs.mp` but running `cagefsctl --remount-all` fixed it. Thanks man!

Answer (score 1):

Is localhost defined in your `/private/etc/hosts` file?

Comment: 127.0.0.1 localhost is in my hosts file.

Comment: `/private`? Never seen that before

Comment: @TheLQ: It's a Mac thing. While there __is__ a symlink from /etc to /private/etc, for some reason Apple generally advises using the "true" path: http://support.apple.com/kb/TA27291

Answer (score 1):

I was having this issue and I could not figure it out. I tried everything I could fine to no avail.

I found that I had a .netrc in /root/ that had info in it.

I deleted it and problem gone.

Able to log into mysql using mysql -uroot -p without issue now.

I know this is an old post but hope this helps someone.

Answer (score 1):

For me, changing the permissions to be publically readable on the parent directory of the mysql.sock fixed the issue:

```
chmod 755 /var/lib/mysql
```

Answer (score 0):

you have to define it in private/etc/hosts I think...  or just use 127.0.0.1 because it is the same thing anyhow, just an alias.

Comment: 127.0.0.1 localhost is in my hosts file.