# Configure xenforo 1.2.9 Using phpmyadmin 4.x with php 5.6.4 on IIS 10, Windows Server 2019

Tags: windows, mysql, php, sql, phpmyadmin

Versions/Programs:
`xenforo 1.2.9, phpmyadmin 4.x, php 5.6.4, MySQL 8.0.32 IIS 10, Windows Server 2019`

I am trying to host a local server for tinkering on an old computer I have. This server will be hosting a XenForo installation. However, my xenforo is 1.2.9 which is outdated and requires php5.6.4. because im using an older php version I also require the phpmyadmin 4.x.

I have all of this installed. **I am aware it would be easier to use up to date software** including xenforo but I purchased this license in 2013 and want to tinker with it before spending any money. I want to set this up for free and then decide if I want tp upgrade everything. The Xenforo directory works fine as I see "begin installation" but cannot begin until I access my databases.

My issue is, when I visit *localhost/phpmyadmin/index.php*, I see the login portal. However, when entering my credentials (which I know are correct) I get this error:

```
mysqli_real_connect(): The server requested authentication method unknown to the client [caching_sha2_password]
 mysqli_real_connect(): (HY000/2054): The server requested authentication method unknown to the client
```

I have been using ChatGPT to help resolve this error but I am at a dead end. It said to add the following code to the *config.ini.php* file:

```
$cfg['blowfish_secret'] = 'S&#QX3LqK6sMtp$PWV?lLfJv0<u4moPe'; /* YOU MUST FILL IN THIS FOR COOKIE AUTH! */
//$cfg['blowfish_secret'] = ')6U}lm)*ZRK|Q82zae=Lv\^FbVVIWp{m';

/**
 * Servers configuration
 */
$i = 0;

/**
 * First server
 */
$i++;
/* Authentication type */
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['auth_type'] = 'cookie';
//$cfg['Servers'][$i]['auth_type'] = 'config';

/* Server parameters */
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['host'] = 'localhost';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['compress'] = false;
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['AllowNoPassword'] = false;

//$cfg['Servers'][$i]['user'] = 'xenforo';
//$cfg['Servers'][$i]['user'] = 'root';

//$cfg['Servers'][$i]['password'] = '{mypass}';
```

I am wondering if this is an issue with my config.ini.php file.  This is the setup:
(I will change the blowfish auth later before deploying)

```
/**
 * This is needed for cookie based authentication to encrypt password in
 * cookie. Needs to be 32 chars long.
 */
$cfg['blowfish_secret'] = 'S&#QX3LqK6sMtp$PWV?;.fJv0<u4mo[e'; /* YOU MUST FILL IN THIS FOR COOKIE AUTH! */

/**
 * Servers configuration
 */
$i = 0;

/**
 * First server
 */
$i++;
/* Authentication type */
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['auth_type'] = 'cookie';
//$cfg['Servers'][$i]['auth_type'] = 'config';

/* Server parameters */
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['host'] = 'localhost';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['compress'] = false;
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['AllowNoPassword'] = false;

//$cfg['Servers'][$i]['user'] = 'root';
//$cfg['Servers'][$i]['password'] = '{mypassword}';
```

ChatGPT is also saying to add the following code to a php file [that connects to mysql database] but I am unsure where to add it:

```
<?php

// Database configuration
define('DB_HOST', 'localhost');
define('DB_USER', 'user');
define('DB_PASS', 'password');
define('DB_NAME', 'database');

// Create a database connection
$link = mysqli_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASS, DB_NAME);

// Set the character set
mysqli_set_charset($link, 'utf8');
```

Please someone help. I am totally lost. If you require more info let me know and I will edit this question.

I have tried:

- disabled the blowfish and tried using the conf file instead (error)
- [mysql_connect(): The server requested authentication method unknown to the client [mysql_old_password] in](https://serverfault.com/questions/385378/mysql-connect-the-server-requested-authentication-method-unknown-to-the-client)

Comment: You need to configure your MySQL instance to allow and accept legacy authentication methods (SHA2 is too new for those obsolete things you use).

Comment: Thank you. I am trying a workaround of setting my xenforo to use php5.6.4 and using the latest phpmyadmin with the latest php version. So far I am getting an error stating: Service Unavailable
HTTP Error 503. The service is unavailable.
I have the applicationHost.config file updated and the correct handler mappings installed. I am unsure what this is happening.